# Reading value from dynamic textbox in C# and difference between data set and data table

Tags: c#-3.0

How do I read the value from a dynamic textbox in C# and difference between data set and data table?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic textbox"? Please give us a *lot* more context - read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: dynamic textbox means text box will be generated when the run time

Answer (score 0):

Design time and run time controls have the same properties.
If you create a textbox manually, you can read/modify its [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) property as if it had been created at design time (assuming WPF).